# How to diagnose Kubernetes Pod Launching problems?

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, azure-aks

I followed these [instructions to create a Hello-World WebApp with C#/.NET Core 3.1 with Visual Studio 2019 V16.5.2 and deployed to Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dev-spaces/get-started-netcore-visualstudio) and it worked great. In addition to being able to debug/single-step with Visual Studio, I could also use the `kubectl run` command and edit the deployment to make it a LoadBalancer and see my hello-world web page in the browser.

Then I published the same image of the WebApp to my personal DockerHub account and tried to deploy to Docker for desktop/Kubernetes. When doing `kubectl get pods -o wide` I saw the status of the pod is *ImagePullBackOff* and `kubectl logs <podname>` fails to give me a log where might have some hints as to the problems.

(1) How does one diagnose a problem like this with no log files?

(2) Could this be a bug since this image works on AKS? I'd prefer to use Docker Desktop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this:
`kubectl describe pod {pd-id}`

it shows whole bunch of the information including errors related to pulling image.

also most probably your `ImagePullBackOff` is related to authentication problem of kubernetes against image registry.